# Вопрос по оптимизации

Tags: php, оптимизация, sql

Здравствуйте, вопрос касается в оптимизации. Возможно ли обьединить 2 запроса в один.

```
  $row = mysql_query("SELECT f.total_votes, c.sub, f.total_value, c.name AS cname, f.category AS catid, f.size, f.uploader FROM xbtit_files as f LEFT JOIN xbtit_categories as c ON c.id = f.category LEFT JOIN xbtit_users as u ON f.uploader=u.id LEFT JOIN xbtit_users_level as l ON u.id_level=l.id ".$wh." ORDER BY ".$r." DESC LIMIT ".$pp.",".$a[1]);  
  while ($b=mysql_fetch_assoc($row)){     
    $mc = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM xbtit_categories WHERE `id`=".$b['sub']));
```

Первый запрос выводит всю информацию о файле. Второй запрос $mc - отвечает за вывод главной категории. Можно ли объединить? Если Вам что-то не понятно или забыл уточнить спрашивайте в комментариях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте еще один

```
LEFT JOIN xbtit_categories AS c1 ON c1.id = c.sub
```

Получится:

```
SELECT 
f.total_votes, c.sub, 
f.total_value, 
c.name AS cname, 
f.category AS catid, 
f.size, f.uploader,
c1.name as subcatname
FROM xbtit_files AS f 
LEFT JOIN xbtit_categories AS c ON c.id = f.category 
LEFT JOIN xbtit_categories AS c1 ON c1.id = c.sub
LEFT JOIN xbtit_users AS u ON f.uploader=u.id 
LEFT JOIN xbtit_users_level AS l ON u.id_level=l.id 
...
```

ЗЫ Очень неудобно анализировать неформатированный запрос, учитывая также ничего не дающие переменные из php.

Answer (score 0):

так что ли?:

```
$row = mysql_query("/*второй запрос*/SELECT `name` FROM xbtit_categories WHERE `id` in /*первый запрос*/(SELECT /*f.total_votes, */c.sub/*, f.total_value, c.name AS cname, f.category AS catid, f.size, f.uploader*/ FROM xbtit_files as f LEFT JOIN xbtit_categories as c ON c.id = f.category LEFT JOIN xbtit_users as u ON f.uploader=u.id LEFT JOIN xbtit_users_level as l ON u.id_level=l.id ".$wh." ORDER BY ".$r." DESC LIMIT ".$pp.",".$a[1].")");
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given.

Comment: Гм, а какой сгенерённый запрос, и что за ошибка у мускула? я в качестве примера показал как объединить, а не для копи-паста.

Comment: Ошибка - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'. Можно как-то исправить?

Comment: Тогда надо разобраться зачем вам нужен limit?